# MVC App Using Hangfire With Multiple Queues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application using Hangfire to enqueue jobs for different parts of the project.

For reference, the project is set up as a single application, with multiple libraries referenced as other projects that we have worked on previously. The hangfire server is set up from the MVC app, and all of the methods that call jobs to be Enqueued are in different controllers on the app. There are different controllers for different referenced libraries.

I was able to successfully create jobs for the first library; they enqueued fine, processed and completed or failed successfully. The problem is now that I have attempted to add a second library to the Hangfire setup, I am getting a `Could not load type 'SPPC_Jobs.Controllers.FB.FBMetricsController' from assembly 'SPPC_Jobs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'` in the Hangfire dashboard when I attempt to Enqueue a new job. Since the enqueuing is happening from the controller in which the library is directly referenced and used, I am stuck as to why this is happening. I am also able to directly call the library's method from the controller's action and it works fine, only running into an issue when it heads to Hangfire.

Here is some code used in the project to demonstrate the setup and how jobs are attempted to be enqueued.

### Startup.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMongoStorage("...");

app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions = { 
    Authorization = System.Linq.Enumerable.Empty<IDashboardAuthorizationFilter() 
});

var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions { Queues = new[] { "scp", "metrics" } };

app.UseHangfireServer(options);
```

Worth noting that it is using a MongoDB configuration. I originally did not have the individual queues in the config options, but after doing some research on this, it looks like that may help. Each controller's action is decorated with a Queue attribute.

### Controller 1

The first controller calls `BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Processor(id), scheduleDate);` which references another action that I created, called `Processor`. Processor takes the ID, queries the database (SQL Server DB, not mongo) for a record, then calls a service in the referenced library, called `ProcessorService`.

```
[Queue("scp")]
public Void Processor(int id) {
    var callback = repo.GetSocialCallback(id);

    //-- Referenced library
    var processorService = new ProcessorService();
    processorService.Process(callback);
}
```

### Controller 2

The second controller calls the second library's method in essentially the same way as the first:

`BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Enqueue(providerClientAccount));`

The enqueue method calls the referenced library's method like so:

```
[Queue("metrics")]
public void Enqueue(ProviderClientAccount providerAccount) {

    //-- Referenced library
    var metricsService = new MetricsService();
    metricsService.Call(providerAccount);
}
```

The only real difference I see is that the second controller is passing an entire object, rather than an ID. I did also try passing just an ID to the `Enqueue` method, querying the object inside that method and then calling it, but still ended up with the same result.

---

All of the questions/tutorials/bugs that I could find on similar situations all used multiple projects with one central app for the Hangfire dashboard, or different configs than what I am currently using. What I don't understand, is that for that second library, when I attempt to enqueue the job, it throws an error saying it can't load type `FBMetricsController` which is the controller from which it is being called, so I don't know what I am missing.

Any help or advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the exact error details in question, not just the first couple words.

Comment: @mason Updated for the exact error!

Comment: Your background method shouldn't call another action. That's why it's trying to load the controller.

Comment: @mason Thanks for the advice, I will definitely update my code. Turns out the bigger problem was that there was an active Azure instance that was running a separate hangfire server without the most up to date code, so it was being picked up there instead of the local server.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the bigger problem was that there was an active Azure instance that was running a separate hangfire server without the most up to date code, so it was being picked up there instead of the local server.